# Similarity measure for short series

Tags: time-series, similarities, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I am looking for the best similarity measure between pairs of equal length series. These are concentrations of molecules measured in discrete fractions, the number of fractions is small (5-6). The fractions follow each other as they came off the chromatography column, so fraction #1 has closer relationship with #2 than with #3. I would like to score a large number of such series how close each of them follow one reference series i.e. they increase/decrease in the same rhythm. The final aim is to select those whice are the most similar to the reference.

First I substracted the minimum and divided with the maximum each series (dimensions and zero points are not the same -- so normalization is necessary, rigth?).

Then I was thinking about [Spearman correlation](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Kendall's tau](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [cosine similarity](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cosine_similarity), and many others came up as I read after. These look good, but I am still a bit confused.

I am wondering which measure would be the most appropriate in this case?

Comment: Have you considered euclidean distance? If you are mostly interested in a rhythm, you could consider standardizing each series.

Comment: thanks @spdrnl, now I am considering euclidean distance too. I decided to try all of them, and see which gives the best sensitivity/specificity compared to a gold standard.

Comment: O.k. If you have a distance measure, then you could also try K-Means clustering if you are interested in similar rhythms.